# Can or how do I get livereload to work with visual studio 2015 RC?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, livereload

Is it possible to get LiveReload or similar program or extension to work with visual studio 2015 RC?  Looking to set up a more real-time web dev.  (I have a back-end background and fairly new to web world.)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Do visit the Help Center to check out how you can improve your question :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible and works relatively well in VS2015.

In the IDE, to the right of the browser selection, there is a "curley arrow".  Click on the drop down for it and select "Enable Browser Link".

This will then do a live reload once changes have been saved.

The only quirk I have found is the way in which the live reload occurs and if you are looking at the developer tools in the browser (Chrome for example) you will  see all XHR requests for the feature (the initiator is shown as BrowserLink).  I've not found a way to avoid that unfortunately.

Comment: I have livereload downloaded and pointed to my dev folder, and I have that enable browser link selected.  css files work well, but html files still require forced refresh.. ?

Comment: Browser link doesn't appear to reload the HTML (or at least when it's part of cshtml filetypes).

Answer (score 1):

You can use gulp and livereload.

There is a very nice article here: [here](http://www.roelvanlisdonk.nl/?p=4296)